# Materialized View returns more results than the query itself Oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am facing such a strange behavior in our database (Oracle 12c):
There is a query than contains a few partition by clauses and subqueries. After we converted it into a materialized view, we are receiving different results than when running a query in isolation.
The code generated by SQLDeveloper to create the object is:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  {MV_name}.{columns}
 ORGANIZATION HEAP PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 163840 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE {our_tablespace}   NO INMEMORY 
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  USING INDEX 
  REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT SYSDATE + 1
  USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  AS
{query}
```

The query is:

```
select process_number, status, LASTCHANGEUSER, date_time, 
rank() over (partition by cos.process_number order by cos.date_time desc) rank
from (

    select  process_number,
             status, 
             grp,
             LASTCHANGEUSER,
             min(jn_datetime) over (partition by process_number, grp order by jn_datetime) as date_time,
             rank() over (partition by process_number, grp order by jn_datetime) as aux_rank
    from     (select process_number,
                     jn_datetime,
                     status,
                     process_jn.LASTCHANGEUSER,
                     row_number() over (partition by process_number order by jn_datetime)
                       - row_number() over (partition by process_number, status order by jn_datetime) grp
              from   process_jn
            )
    ) cos where aux_rank = 1;
```

Anyone has an idea what might have happened there, please??

Comment: The materialized view is set to refresh every day (and not at the same time every day, it'll refresh slightly later every day which seems unlikely to be what you want).  Are you sure that the query alone returns a different set of results when it is run at the time the MV refreshes?  If the underlying table is changing throughout the day, you'd expect the MV to have a different result set than the query.

Comment: the MV has been refreshed a few times manually to deny such case - still number of results is different.
Another symptom that could lead to possible solution is that when the query is wrapped with normal view, there is no issue. The problem is only with MV

Comment: What is the data type of `jn_datetime`?  If `timestamp` are time zones an issue?  Did  you try invoking the query, and in the same session, create the materialized view, and then query the materialized view immediately after creation, then run the stand-alone query again, in the same session immediately after the MV creation and query against the MV?

Comment: That column is timestamp and everything happens within one zone. All statements were run in one session. I ended up converting query results into a table rather than MV. It appears that the reason is real time data consumption (new rows go to the underlying table frequently) although I am pretty sure that any rows related to sample processes I am interested in are neither deleted nor inserted. Weird...